# Multithreading in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
   func credentials() -> AWSTask<AWSCredentials> {
    var task:AWSTask<AWSCredentials>
    // let task=AWSTask<AWSCredentials>(result:nil)
    print("hello")
    let svc=ServerConnection(action: "m_get_token")
    let req=svc.createRequestWithoutBody("POST")
   let queue=DispatchQueue(label: "credentialsqueue")
    task=AWSTask<AWSCredentials>(result:nil)

    svc.getResponse(req){
        (appresp)->Void in


        print("app response data xx is \(appresp)")
        let k=appresp as? NSDictionary
        let datadict=k!["m_response_data"]! as? NSDictionary

        let kid=datadict?["AccessKeyId"]as?String
        let skid=datadict?["SecretAccessKey"]as?String
        let exp=datadict?["Expiration"]as?String
        let stoken=datadict?["SessionToken"]as?String

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: exp!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.cred=AWSCredentials(accessKey: kid!, secretKey: skid!, sessionKey: stoken!, expiration: date!)     
    }
    print("self.cred is \(self.cred!)")
    task=AWSTask<AWSCredentials>(result:self.cred!)
    return task
}
```

In the above code i set up `self.cred` in the secondary thread in the `getResponse` function....which is taking time as it's a server call....`self.cred` in the main thread is returning nil as it is being executed early than before we set up in the secondary thread...how to return the value `self.cred` which is from the secondary thread.(don't stop main thread)User does not have to experience the delay...but nil should not be returned(value in the secondary thread should be returned).

Comment: you may need to use __completion blocks / closures__ instead of the returning a value, there are many examples online which can show you the right way of the concept.

Answer (score 12):

**There are few ways to implement multi-threading in iOS:**

- **NSThread** creates a new low-level thread which can be started by calling the start method.

**Objective C:**

```
    NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
    selector:@selector(myThreadMainMethod:)object:nil];
    [myThread start];
```

**Swift:**

```
var myThread = Thread(target: self, selector: #selector(self.myThreadMainMethod), object: nil)
myThread.start()
```

- **NSOperationQueue** allows a pool of threads to be created and used to execute NSOperations in parallel. NSOperations can also be run on the main thread by asking NSOperationQueue for the mainQueue.

**Objective C:**

```
    NSOperationQueue* myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [myQueue addOperation:anOperation];
    [myQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
         /* Do something. */
    }];
```

**Swift:**

```
var myQueue = NSOperationQueue()
myQueue.addOperation(anOperation)
myQueue.addOperationWithBlock({() -> Void in
    /* Do something. */
})
```

- **GCD or Grand Central Dispatch** is a modern feature of Objective-C that provides a rich set of methods and API's to use in order to support common multi-threading tasks. GCD provides a way to queue tasks for dispatch on either the main thread, a concurrent queue (tasks are run in parallel) or a serial queue (tasks are run in FIFO order).

**Objective C:**

```
    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
       printf("Do some work here.\n");
    });
```

**Swift:**

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)
dispatch_async(queue) {
}
```

**Also Check following links for more details:**

- https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1
- http://www.appcoda.com/grand-central-dispatch/